# [Flutter]: How to create text widgets that can be imported inside?

Tags: flutter

I want to create text widgets that display text fields that can be entered into underlined cells in the image.

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbV0k.png)
I'm (2) _ _ _ _ _ . Today (3) _ _ sunny. _ _ _

Currently I'm writing my text and textfield widgets in widgets wrap , but it doesn't seem to be the most optimal.

```
return const Scaffold(
      body: Wrap(
        spacing: 2,
        children: [
          Text(
            "I'm (2) ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, height: 1.6),
          ),
         SizedBox(
          width: 16,
          child: TextField(
            maxLength: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, height: 1.5),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                counterText: ""),
          ),
          
        ),
         SizedBox(
          width: 16,
          child: TextField(
            maxLength: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, height: 1.5),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                counterText: ""),
          ),
          
        ),
         Text(
            ". Today (3) ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, height: 1.6),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can help you with:

- First, remove the default border from the text field

  ```
  border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
    ),
  ```
- Then, you need to wrap your text field with [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border#-readme-tab-) package.

I hope it will work with you just as you expected.